# JPA: Mapping Value Table to a Field

Tags: java, jpa

I have a question regarding JPA:
My setup is:

A Java Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Annotation")
@SecondaryTable(name = "AnnotationValue", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Hash", referencedColumnName = "Hash"))      
public class Annotation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String ID;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Hash")
    private String Hash;

    private String label;

}
```

and two tables:

```
Annotation
Id    Hash
__________________
1     asdf
```

```
AnnotationValue
Id    Hash    ValueName    Value    Type
__________________________________________
1     asdf    label        example  String
```

Is it possible to tell JPA to fill the field "label" with the corresponding Rows of the "AnnotationValue" table?
If yes how? And if no are there alternatives like defining a custom annotation?

Thank you

Comment: Something is missing from your question. There is no 'label' field shown; you have only mentioned label as what appears to be a value under column "ValueName". It also doesn't make sense to have what appears to be two individually unique keys form a composite primary key. Why are you using a sequence value AND hash for these rows when the sequence value (ID) should be enough to uniquely identify rows? Ignoring 'Hash' from the model, are you just trying to get a ValueName property in the Annotation entity? Just define which table is to be used in your column mappings 'table="AnnotationValue"'

Comment: Thanks for the answer the upper former "level" meant to be label i corrected it. For the composite primary key trust me it makes sense because a third table is involved where the key then plays a role. I just left the third table out because it doesnt corelate with this specific problem.
The problem is that if i do this like following: 
```
@Column(name = "ValueName") 
private String label; 
```
Jpa still doesnt know i only want the rows where label is the value of "ValueName" and then only want the "value" column used as value for label.

Comment: Hash still doesn't make sense: a sequence is unique within the table, making hash redundant - and awkward for foreign keys back to this table. Simple is usually better, and any 3rd or other table needing hash can just use it (history tables maybe?). As for JPA doesn't know you only want certain rows - I don't really know either. Are you trying to filter what is in your Annotation entity? Might be better to map out what the real relationship between these two tables is - I'm guessing you've got a 1:M. How do you want to be able to write to these two tables?

Comment: So i found a really unpleasant workaround where i annotate label as @Transient and then in my repository class fill in the value with an added query. Works so far but isn't really beautiful.

Comment: You are treating this entity as a view object and will have no way that an insert will work. You might want to revisit the model, as if you have other entities for these tables, you can use them to build view objects using constructor queries instead of forcing what seems to be a 1:M relationship into a flat object. But if a separate query to fetch other data works, great.